# What really is the meaning of condescending?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What does *condescending* really mean? So far all the dictionaries do not actually give a single good illustration that shows the behaviour of being condescending.

Comment: The *definition* is what gives that, while the examples show some typical usage. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/condescending) has: *Having or showing an attitude of patronizing superiority*, with one example being: *He evaluates the host culture from his own perspective and approaches it with a condescending or even contemptuous attitude.*

Comment: Wiktionary defines condescension as "the act of condescending; a manner of behaving toward others in an outwardly polite way that nevertheless implies one’s own superiority to the others; patronizing courtesy toward inferiors". So talking to someone as if they were a child or stupid, while still being superficially polite. Are you looking for a more specific example?

Comment: You need to give the various definitions and relate to us how you feel they are lacking. Otherwise we'd only be speculating.

Comment: I already answered this one. [What does 'condescending' exactly mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53437/15299)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'condescending' exactly mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/what-does-condescending-exactly-mean)

Comment: The elevator was out of service and the door was guarded. I don’t understand how the prisoner escaped.  “Uhh, he obviously went down the back staircase,” Tom said condescendingly.